# select box background-image (move to the right by 3px)

Tags: css

I have my location *juustt* about right with the below:

```
select {
  background-image: url("../images/green_check.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 6px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

But I need to go about `3px` --> to the right. The `background-image;` that is and I can't figure out how to achieve this. Integer after defined '`left`' above seems to toggle vertical placement.

Comment: `background-position: 3px 6px`?

Comment: @JonathanSampson that is the answer! (if you want it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position) property takes (up to) two values: distance from left, and distance from top. As such, if you want the background offset `3px` from the left, and `6px` from the top, you should do the following:

```
background-position: 3px 6px;
```

Values can also be preceded by keywords such as *top*, *right*, *bottom*, and/or *left*.